# What method should I use if I want to estimate proportions in a 2xc contingency table (where c >2)?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, group-differences, contingency-tables, methodology

This is a theoretical question, but it's been in the back of my head for a while now.

Let's say I have two groups A and B, and I already know that they differ relative to their distribution on a categorical variable with more than two categories (if you need an example, let's say for instance "favorite hobby" with 4 possible categories: basketball, knitting, hiking, fishing - all mutually exclusive). Let's say I know they differ, because some previous qualitative studies showed they do, however we don't have precise quantitative estimates.

As I know the 2 groups differ, a chi-square test of homogeneity wouldn't be useful here, as I don't want to know if there's a difference between the two groups, but instead I want to estimate by *how much* the two groups differ on each category, *in the population* (i.e. how confident can I be that what I observe in the sample reflects the reality in the population?).

For instance, let's say that I surveyed 200 people in each group A and B (i.e. a total of 400 observations) and I end up with these two distributions for each group:

|  | Basketball | Knitting | Fishing | Hiking | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 8% | 12% | 60% | 20% | 100% (200 people) |
| B | 12% | 15% | 50% | 23% | 100% (200 people) |

So for instance, how accurate/reliable is the observed proportion of people in group A who play basketball (8%)? And what about group B (12%)? And how accurate/reliable is the difference we observe between group A and group B? - same questions for each hobby.

What method could I use to answer these questions? I guess it would involve confidence intervals calculation ([binomial proportion CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)?), but I'm not entirely sure about it, and not sure about how to proceed (an example would be useful I guess, I don't mind formulas and/or code). In addition, I guess that having more than two categories in the variable "hobby" might require some sort of correction (a bit like corrections for multiple testing), should we take that into account?

Secondary question: how should we calculate the required sample size so we can specify a degree of "accuracy" of the estimates/confidence intervals? (I'm not sure if "accuracy" is the right word, so feel free to correct me).

Also, I'm wondering if the sampling method in the example I give above (sampling an equal number in each group A and B) would be correct (e.g. should I rather sample an equal number for each hobby instead?), but that's secondary so you can overlook it if it's too many questions to answer at once.

Comment: But what are the measured variables? What did you use to measure `differ relative to their distribution`?

Comment: user2974951: let's say I sample people from the groups A and B, and I ask them "what is your favorite hobby?", where they can pick one of 4 options. Then I create a contingency table, crosstabulating the variables "group" (A/B) and "hobby" (basketball, etc.). So I have the distribution of hobbies in each group (e.g. 10% of people in group A prefer basketball, 13% knitting, etc., vs. 20%, 8%, etc. in group B).

Comment: I see, so your measured variables are just frequencies? And when testing you probably wish to test the proportions, to see how much they differ between the groups? Which hypotheses do you wish to test then? Specific ones? All combinations? Something else?

Comment: user2974951: Yes, frequencies. I edited my question to add an example, hopefully it should clarify what I have in mind. (But tell me if it doesn't!)

Comment: On the contrary, you *counted* people.  The frequencies are derived quantities.  This is fundamental, because replacing counts by frequencies destroys almost all information about variability.  The "how much" question is answered in the usual ways: subtract or divide counts or perform whatever mathematical operation you deem suitable for the comparison.

Comment: whuber: thanks, sorry, I mixed up the terms "counts" and "frequencies", I'm a bit embarrassed! I can substract or divide counts from my sample, but my question is about what I can learn about the population after these operations.